# dispatch_group_async whitin dispatch_group_notify

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I would like to execute some sequential jobs in a iOS application. I want to ensure that a job is not executed until the previous one has finished. Firstly a tried to do something like this

```
group = dispatch_group_create();
queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
// Job 1
// ...
});
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
// Job 2
// ...
});
```

On this way, sometimes the job 2 start executing when the job 1 is still executing.

Then I though of using this way:

```
group = dispatch_group_create();
queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
// Job 1
// ...
});
dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
// Job 2
// ...
});
```

The behavior is the same, because the job 1 hasn't been asynchronously dispatched, so the `dispatch_group_notify()` function thinks there's nothing executing and the job 2 is dispatched without waiting to the job 1.

I found another solution:

```
group = dispatch_group_create();
queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    // Job 1
    // ...
    });
});
dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    // Job 2
    // ...
    });
});
```

Now everything works fine.

Do you find any problem with this dispatch-inside-dispatch structure? Or is it fine?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you create a *serial* queue using dispatch_queue_create() instead of using the *concurrent* global queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global queue that you get with

```
queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

is a *concurrent* queue. If you want your jobs to execute sequentially, just create
a *serial* queue with

```
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.myqueue", NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easyer than what you did, just use serial queues:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue ;
myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("cua.prova", nil);

dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"Job 1");
});

dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"Job 2");
});

dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"Job 3");
});
```

Job 1 is allways executed before Job 2, and Job 3 after Job 2, but all of them not in main thread

Comment: does this work even if Job 1 is an asynchronous downloading task with completion blocks??
does Job 2 waits??

Comment: yes, it does! Using `dispatch_async` on completion block helped!

Comment: Yes it should, Now I 'm on another project... I remeber this code helped me